# SQL Server query results to SQL dump

Tags: sql-server

How is it possible to export query/view results to `.sql` file?

I want to then import the `.sql` file using Mysql

I tried exporting to a `.CSV` but got broken lines because some of my database values have tabs in it.

I tried using `Tasks -> Generate scripts` but couldn't find an option to export query results.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use tabs for separators then? As for copying data to another database, you can transfer the data with the `Export Data ` wizard, to export the data from SQL Server to any source, including MySQL. You can save the generated SSIS package for execution whenever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a persisted table just for the sake of storing the result query, for example with a

```
SELECT * INTO [your_temporary_persisted_table] FROM source_table
```

Once you have your result data inside a table, right click on the database and pick the "Generate scripts" option from the Tasks submenu. Choose the table you just created. In the Set script options step go to Advanced settings and pick "Data only" in "Types of data to script" option.

Also, if you have a chance to use RedGate's SQL Prompt it has an option to script the query results as an insert right away.